# link list initializing,deleting and showing

Tags: c++, hyperlink, linked-list

i wanted a code that initializes the link list from 1 to 10 ,then deletes the last node and shows the link list each time.
i wrote this code but the first (WHILE) seems to be unlimited that it will the restricted area of RAM!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

// function prototypes
void add_one_to_ten();
void delete_and_show();


struct node
{
    int dat;
    node* nxt;
};

node* Head = NULL;

int main()
{
    add_one_to_ten();
    delete_and_show();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}


//add_one_to_ten function body
void add_one_to_ten()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        node* temp = new node;
        temp->dat = i;
        temp->nxt = Head;
        Head = temp;
    }
}

//delete_and_show function body
void delete_and_show()
{
    node *temp1 = NULL, *temp2 = NULL, *temp3 = NULL;
    // this goes untill we reach a null LL
    while  (Head != NULL)
    {
        //this will show the LL each time
        temp3 = Head;
        while (temp3 != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp3->dat << "  ";
            temp3 = temp3->nxt;
        }
        cout << endl;
        if (Head == NULL)
            cout << "The list is empty.\n";
        else
        {
            temp1 = Head;
            while (temp1->nxt != NULL)
            {
                temp2 = temp1;
                temp1 = temp1->nxt;
            }
            delete temp1;
            temp2->nxt = NULL;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to step through the code in a debugger. And fix the horrendous indentation so you can figure out whether it's properly structured.

Comment: Yes, please, fix the indentation.

Comment: Done. It was making me dizzy. Regarding the endless loop, Note you never update the value of `Head` anywhere in your removal code. Consequently, it is effectively a `while(true)` loop, which you can expect is going nowhere fast.

Comment: I almost feel like this is a class (no pun intended) assignment. Here's a hint: in `delete_and_show`, at what point does `Head` get modified in any way?

Comment: @WhozCraig I think deleting the elements (which is done in <delete temp1>) is like updating the Head.because Head itself should not be moved,im just removing the elements untill i reach a NULL.

Comment: Inside your loop `Head` is never `NULL` because you never touch it. Also, your functions should only do one thing. If you want to delete your list, make a `delete_list` function and if you want to print call `show`.

Comment: @aligholami "... is like updating the Head" - Well, think again. Consider this: `int a = 5, b = a; b = 0;` What you're describing would have the expectation that `b = 0` also changes `a` to `0`. That the variables are pointers make no difference. The logic is flawed regardless.

Comment: @WhozCraig Dear friend :)) I was totally aware of this mistake.i was talking about pointers.when you point to sth,obviously your are mentioning that(sth). this (sth) is Head here.